# Offset lineplot from Y-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am working with a data stream and for different time points in this stream I have density estimates over a fixed set of X values.
Each of these sets of estimates would look something like this

[image]

**I'd like to plot multiple curves like this sideways**, similar to how it's done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15142854/944732)

[image]

I've looked through the documentation regarding plotting but didn't find a straight-forward solution for it.

While it's easy to turn such a plot sideways by simply switching the axes, I didn't find a possibility to offset this from the Y-axis

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle this?

Comment: Why would giving the (x,y) points that you want plotted not work?

Comment: just noticed that I should just add the offset to the density values and that should do the trick. I'll close this in case that actually works out later

Comment: you can also answer your own question

Comment: I will, when I have a stable internet connection again ;)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of plotting

```
plot(x,y)
```

plot

```
plot(k+y,x)
```

where `k` is the location of the plot along the x axis (2 or 4 in your example).